# Error getting App Check token; using placeholder token instead. Error: com.google.firebase.FirebaseException: No AppCheckProvider installed

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-app-check

Error getting App Check token; using placeholder token instead. Error: com.google.firebase.FirebaseException: No AppCheckProvider installed
When users add images to Firebase, the image doesn't get stored i am added appcheck plugin but the error message getting i dont know where to add appcheck in this code error. i just added my firebase appcheck plugins and dependencies

```
const String kTestString = 'Hello world!';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  final FirebaseApp app = await Firebase.initializeApp(
    name: 'test',
    options: FirebaseOptions(
      apiKey: '',
      appId: (Platform.isIOS || Platform.isMacOS)
          ? ''
          : '',
      messagingSenderId: '',
      projectId: 'flutter-firebase-plugins',
    ),
  );
  final firebase_storage.FirebaseStorage storage =
  firebase_storage.FirebaseStorage.instanceFor(
      app: app, bucket: 'gs://flutter-firebase-plugins.appspot.com');
  runApp(MyApp(storage: storage));
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  MyApp({required this.storage});
  final firebase_storage.FirebaseStorage storage;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Storage Example',
      home: MyHomePage(storage: storage),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({required this.storage});
  final firebase_storage.FirebaseStorage storage;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey();
  List<firebase_storage.UploadTask> _tasks = <firebase_storage.UploadTask>[];

  Future<void> _uploadFile() async {
    final String uuid = Uuid().v1();
    final Directory systemTempDir = Directory.systemTemp;
    final File file = await File('${systemTempDir.path}/foo$uuid.txt').create();
    await file.writeAsString(kTestString);
    assert(await file.readAsString() == kTestString);
    final firebase_storage.Reference ref =
    widget.storage.ref().child('text').child('foo$uuid.txt');
    final firebase_storage.UploadTask uploadTask = ref.putFile(
      file,
    );

    setState(() {
      _tasks.add(uploadTask);
    });
  }

  Future<void> _downloadFile(firebase_storage.Reference ref) async {
    final String downloadUri = await ref.getDownloadURL();
    var fileDownloadUri = Uri.parse(downloadUri);
    final String uuid = Uuid().v1();

    final http.Response downloadData = await http.get(fileDownloadUri);
    final Directory systemTempDir = Directory.systemTemp;
    final File tempFile = File('${systemTempDir.path}/tmp$uuid.txt');

    if (tempFile.existsSync()) {
      await tempFile.delete();
    }

    await tempFile.create();
    assert(await tempFile.readAsString() == "");
    final firebase_storage.DownloadTask task = ref.writeToFile(tempFile);

    final int byteCount = (await task).totalBytes;
    final String tempFileContents = await tempFile.readAsString();
    assert(tempFileContents == kTestString);

    assert(byteCount == kTestString.length);

    final String fileContents = downloadData.body;
    final String name = ref.name;
    final String bucket = ref.bucket;
    final String path = ref.fullPath;

    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
      SnackBar(
        content: Text(
            'Success!\n Downloaded $name \n from url: $fileDownloadUri @ bucket: $bucket\n '
                'at path: $path \n\nFile contents: "$fileContents" \n'
                'Wrote "$tempFileContents" to tmp.txt',
            style: const TextStyle(color: Color.fromARGB(255, 0, 155, 0))),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final List<Widget> children = <Widget>[];
    _tasks.forEach((firebase_storage.UploadTask task) {
      final Widget tile = UploadTaskListTile(
        task: task,
        onDismissed: () => setState(() => _tasks.remove(task)),
        onDownload: () => _downloadFile(task.snapshot.ref),
      );
      children.add(tile);
    });
    return Scaffold(
      key: _scaffoldKey,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Flutter Storage Example'),
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
            icon: const Icon(Icons.clear_all),
            onPressed:
            _tasks.isNotEmpty ? () => setState(() => _tasks.clear()) : null,
          )
        ],
      ),
      body: ListView(
        children: children,
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _uploadFile,
        tooltip: 'Upload',
        child: const Icon(Icons.file_upload),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class UploadTaskListTile extends StatelessWidget {
  const UploadTaskListTile(
      { Key? key,  this.task,  this.onDismissed,  this.onDownload})
      : super(key: key);

  final firebase_storage.UploadTask? task;
  final VoidCallback? onDismissed;
  final VoidCallback? onDownload;

  String _bytesTransferred(firebase_storage.TaskSnapshot snapshot) {
    return '${snapshot.bytesTransferred}/${snapshot.bytesTransferred}';
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<firebase_storage.TaskSnapshot>(
      stream: task?.snapshotEvents,
      builder: (BuildContext context,
          AsyncSnapshot<firebase_storage.TaskSnapshot> asyncSnapshot) {
        Widget subtitle= '' as Widget;
        final firebase_storage.TaskSnapshot? snapshot = asyncSnapshot.data;
        final firebase_storage.TaskState? state = snapshot?.state;
        if (asyncSnapshot.hasError) {
          if (asyncSnapshot.error is FirebaseException &&
              (asyncSnapshot.error as FirebaseException).code == 'canceled') {
            subtitle = const Text('Upload canceled');
          } else {
            subtitle = const Text('Something went wrong');
          }
        } else if (snapshot != null) {
          subtitle = Text('status: ${_bytesTransferred(snapshot)} bytes sent');
        }
        return Dismissible(
          key: Key(task.hashCode.toString()),
          onDismissed: (_) => onDismissed!(),
          child: ListTile(
            title: Text('Upload Task #${task.hashCode}'),
            subtitle: subtitle,
            trailing: Row(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: <Widget>[
                if (state == firebase_storage.TaskState.running)
                  IconButton(
                      onPressed: task?.pause, icon: const Icon(Icons.pause)),
                if (state == firebase_storage.TaskState.running)
                  IconButton(
                      onPressed: task?.cancel, icon: const Icon(Icons.cancel)),
                if (state == firebase_storage.TaskState.paused)
                  IconButton(
                    icon: const Icon(Icons.file_upload),
                    onPressed: task?.resume,
                  ),
                if (state == firebase_storage.TaskState.success)
                  IconButton(
                    icon: const Icon(Icons.file_download),
                    onPressed: onDownload,
                  ),
                if (state == firebase_storage.TaskState.success)
                  IconButton(
                    icon: const Icon(Icons.link),
                    onPressed: onDownload,
                  ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```